# How to stop log spamming pinohttp on graphql nestjs

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs

I am using the following npm packages to log in my nestjs graphql service:

`nestjs-pino`
`pino-http`

when I am using the GraphQL playground I am getting a lot of log spams, I have tried to mute those logs but I see those are `POST` request to `/graphql` and I cannot exclude those because I want to see what happens to queries.

current configuration of the module in my nestjs app:

```
LoggerModule.forRoot({
      pinoHttp: {
        transport: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? { target: "pino-pretty" } : undefined,
        formatters: {
          level: (label) => {
            return {
              level: label
            };
          }
        }
      },
      exclude: [{ path: "healthcheck", method: RequestMethod.ALL }]
    })
```